# What is this hash doing?

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and don't really understand the following code.

```
DATA my_table;
     IF _n_=1 THEN DO;   
        DECLARE hash my_hash(hashexp: 4,dataset: "my_dataset");
        rc = my_hash.definekey("my_var1");
        rc = my_hash.definedata("my_var2","my_var3");
        rc = my_hash.definedone();
        CALL missing(rc, my_var1,my_var2,my_var3);
    END;

    SET my_other_dataset;
RUN;
```

The person who gave me this code said that it was doing a 'hash-join'. From the research I've done hasexp:4 means that we are using 2^4 'buckets' for our hash. The bit I'm really not getting is the 'rc=' parts. What is going on here?

Comment: This appears to be setting the return code from the method to a variable, essentially a status code whether the operation was successful or not, you can see the definition for `rc` here on one of the method doc pages: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lecompobjref/n0idnipdo4awyun1q8zv7427r23f.htm. I am not personally a SAS developer so that's why I'm not submitting a full answer, its possible other people have additions or clarifications, to me it just looks like an unchecked return code.

Comment: You don't seem to have the whole program.  As written it is just copying MY_OTHER_DATASET with the added complication of first trying to stuff MY_DATSAET into a HASH object that is never used for anything.

Answer (score 4):

'rc' is often shorthand for 'return code'. The define...() methods don't really need their result returning into a return code. It's more often used on the other hash methods, e.g. .find() or .check() to determine whether the hash lookup was successful.

Also, the code isn't actually performing any lookups in the hash table, as there's no .find() or .check() method calls. It's simply loading 'my_dataset' into the hash table.

I'd expect it to look more like the below :

```
DATA my_table;
    SET my_other_dataset;

     if 0 then set my_dataset ; /* load variables from my_dataset into PDV */
     IF _n_=1 THEN DO;   
        DECLARE hash my_hash(hashexp: 4,dataset: "my_dataset");
        rc = my_hash.definekey("my_var1");
        rc = my_hash.definedata("my_var2","my_var3");
        rc = my_hash.definedone();
    END;

    CALL missing(rc,my_var2,my_var3);

    /* assuming my_var1 is in 'my_other_dataset' */
    rc = my_hash.find() ;

    /* rc will equal zero if the value of my_var1 from my_other_dataset is found in my_dataset,
       and my_var2 & my_var3 will be populated with the corresponding value from the 
       hash table */
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

`rc=` is capturing the return code value from the invoked method of the hash component object.

The documentation states:

> **rc**
>
> specifies whether the method succeeded or failed.
>
> A return code of zero indicates success; a nonzero value indicates failure. If you do not supply a return code variable for the method call, and the method fails, then an appropriate error message is written to the log.

Because the step never takes action based on the return code there is really no need for it in this scenario.